# array insertion or bubble sort

Tags: arrays, sorting, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

Write a program to enter the following elements of an array at run time -

12, 46, 56, 92,43,53,31,10

There should be two choices for the user to sort the array elements either by insertion sort or by bubble sort.

Users can choose the sorting method at run time. One sorting method at a time should work according to the user’s choice.

I think I should  make a program like initialize array with these elements and then with using switch case we should ask user for a preference like bubble sort or selection sort like display a list of choice then same array will be sorted in both the codes of switch

Comment: am i ryt? tell tell .

Comment: You've described a process, but have not asked a question.